# Using Reflection in Android

Tags: java, android, reflection

I am trying to use reflection in the following way (trying to store a class name inside a variable)

```
String ClassName="";
if(someConditoin)
    ClassName="MyFragment";
else
    ClassName="MyAnotherFragment";

fragmentManager.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.animator.translate_fragment_left_to_right, R.animator.translate_fragment_source_left_to_right)
                            .replace(R.id.container, new ClassName())
                            .commit();
```

Is anything like this possible? The fragment that is going to be used will be determined dynamically. There should be some support for this type of functionality.

Answer (score 2):

```
Class.forName(ClassName).newInstance()
```

And, of course, *ClassName* needs to be fully qualified name.

Or, why to just not create a proper object in the *if* statement?

Comment: @Ashwin I mean *if(someConditoin)
    object = new MyFragment();
else
    object = new MyAnotherFragment();*

Comment: yup, `Fragment fragment; if(something) { fragment = new MyFragment(); } else { fragment = new MyAnotherFragment(); }` - same amount of code